# Can a text file used as a pipe?

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I wrote some code for practicing the usage of pipe and met some problems.

For the code below, I tried to make a named pipe to write/read. But if there are some words inside my text file, my code doesn't work. I have expected that the output will print out the words inside the text file and the string I wrote in. Can't I use a .txt file as a pipe? How can I use pipe to modify a text file? Thanks for your helps!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char *myfifo = "pipe_tx2.txt";
    char buf[MAX];

    /* create the fifo */
    mkfifo(myfifo, 666);

    /* write string to the pipe */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    write(fd, "hello", sizeof("hello"));
    close(fd);

    /* read and display message from pipe */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buf, MAX);
    printf("we got: %s\n", buf);
    close(fd);

    /* remove the pipe */
    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not checking the return value from `mkfifo()`, `write()`, or `read()`.  So you don't know what's working and what isn't.  You don't even know if your `open()` calls succeed or not.

Comment: okay, thanks for help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "if there are some words inside my text file, my code doesn't work".  Are you saying that you have an existing regular file with the same name as the FIFO you are trying to create?  If so, then no, that absolutely will not work.  A FIFO is a special *kind* of file, not a special *use* for a file.

Comment: yes, I have an existing file with the same name. I am wondering since we all use a file descriptor for pipe or .txt file, is it okay to use .txt as a pipe? From the response at this website, I guess I cannot use these two together.

Comment: `666` is decimal, but it should be octal `0666`

Comment: If you have an existing file with the same name, `mkfifo` will return `-1` (a failure) and set `errno = EEXIST`.

Comment: You mean use ".txt" extension to name a named pipe? Sure you can, there is no concept of file extension in standard Unix filesystems, any string is acceptable to name any type of *file*.

Comment: regarding the call to `mkfifo()`,  the permissions in the second parameter are modified by the `umask`,  So you want the `umask` to be set properly, otherwise the resulting named pipe will not be accessable as you expect it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some problems in your code. First as everybody noticed, your access rights are wrong, specify them in octal `0666`.

But, worst, the semantic of open/read/write on a named pipe are different than for a regular file. `open` for writing a named pipe is blocked until someone opened it for reading, and the converse. So a single process can't use named pipe this way (remember that pipes are normally designed to communicate in between processes). What you need is to open for reading first in non-blocking mode, then immediatly set the  mode to blocking for the future, and then open for writing, such that the writing part will be available.

Another problem is that you don't send correct data. You should use `strlen` to catch the length of a C-string and add one to count and include the NUL terminating char, so reading a full C-string will be correct on the other part.

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is that you use `666` instead of `0666` for the mode of the FIFO, which means you do not have permission to read it.  Code with more error checking will demonstrate this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#define MAX 100

int main()
{
    int pid;
    char *myfifo = "pipe_tx2.txt";

    unlink(myfifo);             /* if it already exists */
    /* create the fifo */
    if (mkfifo(myfifo, 666)) {
        perror(myfifo);
        return 1;
    }

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!pid) {
        /* child process - read and display message from pipe */
        char buf[MAX];
        int fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
        int bytes_read;
        if (fd < 0) {
            perror(myfifo);
            return 1;
        }

        bytes_read = read(fd, buf, MAX);
        if (bytes_read < 0) {
            perror("read");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("We got: %*s\n", bytes_read, buf);
        close(fd);
        return 0;
    }

    {
        /* parent process - write string to the pipe */
        static const char message[] = "hello";
        sleep(2);               /* just to show that the child blocks until we write */

        int fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
        int bytes_written;
        if (fd < 0) {
            perror(myfifo);
            return 1;
        }
        write(fd, message, sizeof message);
        if (bytes_written <= 0) {
            perror("write");
            return 1;
        }
        close(fd);
    }

    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

    /* remove the pipe */
    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;
}
```

Change the mode to `0666` and you no longer get `pipe_tx2.txt: Permission denied` from the reading process.